# Nginx redirection magic

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-route53

I have a third-party that's forwarding traffic over to me on a subdomain - let's call it **subdomain.thirdparty.com**

I would like to forward this traffic over to **www.mysite.com/subdomain** - this is where the app lives. The links in the app require the /subdomain part in the URL.

BUT I would like to maintain the third-party URL in the browser, something like **subdomain.thirdparty.com** or **subdomain.thirdparty.com/subdomain**

I'm hosted on AWS so I have Route 53 available to me, and have the following Nginx setup:

```
server{
    server_name *.mysite.com;
    listen 80;

    location /subdomain/{
        proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /subdomain;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9014;
    }
}
```

I've tinkered around with Nginx settings but just can't seem to figure it out. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you can redirect to some random site and keep the URL. What you can do is craft a rewrite rule and load a particular document root.

Comment: @Peter Even if it's my site? This is another point of confusion I have.

Comment: Yes, if it is your site you can achieve this. Rewrite the domain to /subdomain or `subdomain.thirdparty.com` and have a vhost that points a document root to the app.